# moving a mxn window inside image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have images of sizes MxN .What I want to do now is that I want to create a window mxn with step size that of 1/4th of the Image and move it inside the image from left to right and top to bottom and then i would calculate pixel density that is

```
pixel density in a window= Number of white pixels/Total Number of pixels
```

and for some fixed pixel density say 0.45 I would set the center pixel of the window to be 1 or 0.

Is there some predefined functions I could make use of in matlab.

**update**

I have done the following effort

```
function result=imagePixelDensity(Image,window,thresh)
    [WidthI,HeightI]=size(Image);
    [WidthW,HeightW]=size(window);
    totalDensity=WidthW*HeightW;
    stepW=WidhtI/4;
    for r=1:WidthI
        for c=1:HeightI
            if(c+stepW<WidthI && WidhtW+stepW <WidthI)
                Temp=Image(r:HeightW,c+stepW:WidthW+stepW);
                dens=sum(Temp(:))/totalDensity;
                if(dens>=thres)   
                      % donot know what to do here like setting or clearing                   
                       %pixel in a window
                end


                stepW=stepW+WidthW;
            end
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going into the loops you could use a very simple function of `blockproc` by setting proper values of `BorderSize`. An example could be:

```
mypxden = @(block_struct) ...
sum(block_struct.data(:))/(size(block_struct.data,1)*size(block_struct.data,2)/4);
I_proc = blockproc(I,[1,1],mypxden,'BorderSize',[round(((size(I,1)/4)-1)/2),round(((size(I,2)/4)-1)/2)],'TrimBorder',false);
```